# Merge description and reviews tab on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to merge Description and Review tabs on Woocommerce. Reviews should be below Description

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'exetera_custom_product_tabs', 98 );
function exetera_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // Custom description callback.
    $tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
        global $post, $product;


        // Display the content of the Description tab.
        the_content();


        // Display the heading and content of the Additional Information tab.

        echo '<h2>Opinie</h2>';

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', $product );
    };

    // Remove the additional information tab.
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );

    return $tabs;
}
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'exetera_custom_product_tabs', 98 );
function exetera_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // Custom description callback.
    $tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
        global $post, $product;


        // Display the content of the Description tab.
        the_content();


        // Display the heading and content of the Additional Information tab.
        echo '<h2>Opinie</h2>';

        wc_get_template( 'single-product-reviews.php' );

    };

    // Remove the additional information tab.
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );

    return $tabs;
}
```